# Unable to make use of the `Apply Filters` button on a webpage through the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

When I navigate to this [WEBPAGE](https://printerdirectory.usps.com/listing/#/) and enter this search address: `New York City, New York, USA`, I can see search results on the webpage. The script I've pasted below can produce the same.

However, now I wish to make use of the `Filter results` button to change a few things from the options, as in `Printing  your mailpiece` from `SERVICES`, `within 50 miles` from `DISTANCE` and `By distance` from `SORT` and then `Apply Filters` button to filter the results, which I can't do.

```
import time
import requests

url = 'https://printerdirectory.usps.com/listing/api/vendors'
link = 'https://gis.usps.com/arcgis/rest/services/locators/EDDM_Composite/GeocodeServer/suggest'
params = {
    'text': 'New York City, New York, USA',
    'f': 'json'
}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Origin': 'https://printerdirectory.usps.com',
    'Referer': 'https://printerdirectory.usps.com/'
}
result_params = {
    'noCache': ''
}
result_headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Host': 'printerdirectory.usps.com',
    'Referer': 'https://printerdirectory.usps.com/listing/',
    'Location': '',
    'Key': '',
    'Type': 'key',
    'Lazyupdate': '[object Object]'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    result_headers['Location'] = res.json()['suggestions'][0]['text']
    result_headers['Key'] = res.json()['suggestions'][0]['magicKey']
    s.headers.update(result_headers)
    unixtime = int(time.time()*1000)
    result_params['noCache'] = unixtime
    resp = s.get(url,params=result_params)
    print(resp.json()['vendors'])
```

How can I make use of the `Apply Filters` button through the requests module?

Comment: first you may have to use `DevTools` (tab `Network`) in `Chrome` or `Firefox` to see how page send it. Usually pages uses `POST` request but you use `GET` request.

Comment: there can other problem. Page uses JavaScript to display data - so it may also use JavaScript to filter data - without loading data from server.

Comment: I don't see any readable values in data which it sends to server - maybe it use JavaScript to encrypt it. Maybe you will have to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser.

Comment: Okay, I've found the option for changing distance using the requests module, but I could not find the options for the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example how you can download the data from the server (the actual parameters are stored as HTTP headers):

```py
import requests

url = "https://printerdirectory.usps.com/listing/api/vendors"

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(
        {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0"
        }
    )

    s.get("https://printerdirectory.usps.com/listing/")

    headers = {
        "radius": "50",
        "type": "key",
        "location": "New York City, New York, USA",
        "key": "GST7YMc0AM9UOsE2JPpREYcnDh4nYSWGOocpZg5pDTyaHSybHgE0njypIjTmObELDU4QHgc0Y1ckOgc-J5KJQ5xaMs8F",
    }

    s.headers.update(headers)

    data = s.get(url).json()
    for i, vendor in enumerate(data["vendors"], 1):
        # I guess 1 means Printing service
        if 1 in vendor["services"]:
            print(f"{i:>3} {vendor['name']:>40}")
```

Prints:

```
  1                          MINUTEMAN PRESS
  2                       POST HERITAGE INC.
  3                          MINUTEMAN PRESS
  4                            POSTNET NY143
  5           MINUTEMANPRESS OF FOREST HILLS
  6                            POSTNET NY133
  7                     THE UPS STORE # 3867
  8                          MINUTEMAN PRESS

...
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I guess using the value of radius in the headers and filtering the services from the results is the only way to achieve that through the requests module.